# jQuery DOM parser?

Tags: jquery, parsing, dom

I've got a jQuery script that calls out to the Yahoo Boss API and retrieves a list of keywords related to a seed keyword phrase. Once the script has the keyword list, I'm then writing these keywords to the screen, each in a span tag to allow the user to add them to their post/page content (WordPress)

The script is working great and now I'd like to enhance it a bit so that I can highlight a keyword in the listing if it already appears inside the content being edited.

What I need to do is to parse the contents of a textarea (the WordPress content editor) and for every matching term that exists in the content, I need to apply a special style to the keyword's span tag in the LSI list.

I'm looking for your suggestions on resources or examples on using javascript and jQuery to parse the innerText (aka content sans html tags) content of the WordPress content editor.

For example, I have a button which when clicked, executes the following jQuery which pulls a listing of keywords, then adds them to a string "result" to write them to the screen...

```
for (key in keywords){if (keywords[key] > 5) result += '<span>' + key + ',</span>';}
```

So what I need to do is to evaluate, for each keyword returned inside the loop, if it appears in the content editor (jQuery('#content').html()) and if so, I need to add a highlight class to the span. Otherwise, leave it as is.

Comment: When you say "sans HTML tags", do you mean it's entirely plaintext, or that it's not a complete HTML document (i.e. missing the `<head>`)?  Specifically, are those spans you mentioned in the textarea?  You might get a better answer if you show us an example of "before" and what you're hoping to achieve "after".

Comment: Hi Dave, I've actually managed to get the alert above to work properly but it must be called after page load. That was the first problem. What I mean by sans html is that I only want to evaluate the content without html tags. e.g., <a title="foo"> should not be part of the content that being parsed so that if a keyword is "foo" and it only appears in the alt text of an html element, I don't want to highlight it as a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the contents as an HTML string, here would be one case-sensitive way to do it, with filled-in example variables shown above the meat of the function.

```
var content = "<div>But this is a div!</div><p>This is a paragraph.  Do you like this paragraph?</p>";

// append to a div to make sure there's a top-level tag.
var html = $("<div></div>").append(content).html();

// keywordList is a selector for a div containing spans of items representing the contents
$("#keywordList").find("span").filter(function() {
    return html.indexOf($(this).html()) != -1;
}).each(function() {
    $(this).html("<span class='highlight'>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
});
```

Here's the test HTML:

```
<div id="keywordList">
    <span>paragraph</span><br />
    <span>span</span><br />
    <span>ul</span><br />
    <span>div</span><br />
    <span>ol</span><br />
    <span>table</span><br />
</div>
```

You can [see this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/3xvgd/2/).

Comment: Wow, pretty sweet example justkt. +1 Thanks!

Comment: Justkit, just to clarify. What I'm looking to do is to highlight a list of keywords *outside* the content editor, not highlight the words inside the content (although I think that will be helpful to, but I dont want to alter the markup just for the span highlights, so it must be a runtime only styling). So I'm looking to highlight the keyword where it appears in a list outside the content editor, if the content editor contains the keyword.

Comment: @Scott B- I have updated my example to fit your use case a little better.

Comment: Thanks Justkt. Perfect example. I appreciate the help!

Comment: How difficult is it to make the search case-insensitive?

Comment: @Scott B - not hard at all.  In the filter function make both `html` and `$(this).html()` lowercase using Javascript's `.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 0):

The content text area may be getting converted to iframe dynamically for advanced editing features and you may need to grab and manipulate the iframe content using the [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) function in jquery. Use firebug to find out what the actual tag of content text area converted to.