# jQuery insert a class on a node during a find().each() recurse?

Tags: jquery

In the jQuery below, the highlight span is being inserted into the existing span, creating a nested span element. is it possible to amend the script so that it just adds a highlight class to the existing span, rather than creating a new span?
([props and thanks to justkt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779691/jquery-dom-parser) for the example)

```
var content = jQuery('#content').html();

// append to a div to make sure there's a top-level tag.
var html = jQuery("<div></div>").append(content).html();

// keywordList is a selector for a div containing spans of items representing the contents
jQuery(".my_related_kw").find("span").filter(function() {
    return html.indexOf(jQuery(this).html()) != -1;
}).each(function() {
    jQuery(this).html("<span class='highlight'>" + jQuery(this).html() + "</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `addClass` to add the `class='hightlight'` to the existing `<span>` after your `filter`.

```
jQuery(".my_related_kw").find("span").filter(function() {
    return html.indexOf(jQuery(this).html()) != -1;
}).addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: +1 Sweet. Off to Amazon for a jQuery book. I'm ready to dive in. Any suggestions?

Comment: Whatever has the most recent version and best reviews. That's how I pick. I converted from Prototype, so I never got a book.

Answer (score 0):

Use the addClass() function.

```
}).each(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

As per Jason's answer, you don't actually need the .each() anymore since addClass will work on a collection of elements.